# Copying options and optiongroups with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a found a great jQuery snippet that allows copying of an option from one selector to another and back.

I would like to modify it to add option groups and when all options are moved from one side to another, have the option group removed from empty group and add it to the full group in the new selector.
Can something like that be accomplished with just using jQuery?

**HTML:**

```
<select multiple id="select1" class="w100p">                
    <optgroup label="Group 1">
      <option value="1">Option 1a</option>
      <option value="2">Option 1b</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group 2">
      <option value="3">Option 2a</option>
      <option value="4">Option 2b</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>

<a href="#" id="add">add >></a>
<br>
<a href="#" id="remove"><< remove</a>

<select multiple id="select2" class="w100p"></select>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    return !$('#select1 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select2');
});
$('#remove').click(function() {
    return !$('#select2 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select1');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m97zR/1/)

Comment: BTW, nice way of succinctly returning false. Took me a minute to realize what was going on there...

Comment: `I would like to modify it to add option groups and when all options are moved from one side to another, have the option group removed from empty group and add it to the full group in the new selector.` Not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Can you try to explain yourself a little better...?

Comment: I added a DEMO link to my messages.

Comment: Your demo seems to be working fine. What are missing there?

Comment: Well, couple of things. If I copy option to thr right and then click REMOVE, it sahould go back to the same option group. Also if I add both options from left to the right selector, the Option Group label needs to disappear from left and appear with the group in the right selector. And if i remove all option from the right, it need to move to the left with option group label. I think i need to use multidimentional arrays here...

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/m97zR/2/) then?

Comment: Almost... It does copy the group label, but once all options in a group have been copied, the group header in the left box needs to be removed. Also clicking "remove" should send options right back, and currently they do not fall into groups...

Comment: Well then, here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/m97zR/3/ . This could use a lot of work, but it's a start, and is as far as I'm willing to go with this for now. Modify and enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is not perfect, it should get you started:

```
var $select1 = $('#select1');
    $select2 = $('#select2');

$('option').each(function(){
    $(this).data('optgroup', $(this).parent().attr('label'));
});

$('#add').click(function() {
    var $el = $('#select1 option:selected'),
        groupName = $el.data('optgroup'),
        $parent = $el.parent(),
        $optgroup = $select2.find('optgroup[label="' + groupName + '"]');

    if ( ! $el.length ) return false;

    if ( ! $optgroup.length ) $optgroup = $('<optgroup label="' + $el.data('optgroup') + '" />').appendTo($select2);

    $el.appendTo( $optgroup );

    if ( ! $parent.children().length ) $parent.remove();

    return false;
});
$('#remove').click(function() {
    var $el = $('#select2 option:selected'),
        groupName = $el.data('optgroup'),
        $parent = $el.parent(),
        $optgroup = $select1.find('optgroup[label="' + groupName + '"]');

    if ( ! $el.length ) return false;

    if ( ! $optgroup.length ) $optgroup = $('<optgroup label="' + $el.data('optgroup') + '" />').appendTo($select1);

    $el.appendTo( $optgroup );

    if ( ! $parent.children().length ) $parent.remove();

    return false;
});
```

Like I said, it needs some additional work (like consolidating the 2 functions; they're basically doing the same thing), but should get you started.

Finally, here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m97zR/3/

Comment: If you move multiple options from multiple option groups, in a single action, then they are erroneously consolidated into a single option group.

Comment: @Chalky - Correct. This is not production-ready code. It's just here as a starter to get the OP started down the right path.

Answer (score 1):

Better solution below. It hides empty optgroups and remembers ownership of moved options. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m97zR/31/

```
var $select1 = $('#select1');
var $select2 = $('#select2');

$([$select1, $select2]).each(function(){
    $(this).find('optgroup').each(function(idx){
        var ogId = 'og' + idx;
        $(this).attr('id', ogId);
        $(this).find('option').each(function(){
            $(this).data('parent', ogId);
        });
    });
});

$('#add').click(function() {
    processOptions($select1, $select2);
});
$('#remove').click(function() {
    processOptions($select2, $select1);
});

var optgFoundInTarget = {};

function processOptions(source, target) {
    var selectedOptions = $(source).find('option:selected');
    if (selectedOptions.length) {
        selectedOptions.each(function(){
            var movingFromOptGroup = $(this).parent();
            parentOg = $(movingFromOptGroup).attr('id');
            if (parentOg.indexOf('_target') > -1) {
                parentOg = parentOg.replace('_target', '');
            } else {
                parentOg += '_target';
            }
            if (typeof optgFoundInTarget[parentOg] == 'object') {
            } else {
                if (target.find('optgroup#'+parentOg).length) {
                    _el = target.find('optgroup#'+parentOg);
                } else {
                    _el = $('<optgroup id="' + $(movingFromOptGroup).attr('id') + '_target" label="' + $(movingFromOptGroup).attr('label') + '" />').appendTo(target);
                }
                optgFoundInTarget[parentOg] = _el;
            }
            targetOptGroup = optgFoundInTarget[parentOg];
            $(this).data('parent', $(targetOptGroup).attr('id')).appendTo(targetOptGroup);
        });
        $([source, target]).each(function(){
            $(this).find('optgroup').each(function(){
                $(this).css('display', $(this).find('option').length ? 'inline' : 'none');
            });
        });
        target.val(null);
    }
}
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
                $(function () {
                    var $select1 = $('#secenekgruplari');
                    var $select2 = $('#secilisecenekler');

                    $('option').each(function () {
                        $(this).data('optgroup', $(this).parent().attr('label'));
                    });

                    $('#add').click(function () {
                        var $el = $('#secenekgruplari option:selected');

                        $el.each(function(){
                            groupName = $(this).data('optgroup'),
                            $parent = $(this).parent(),
                            $optgroup = $select2.find('optgroup[label="' + groupName + '"]');
                            if (!$optgroup.length) $optgroup = $('<optgroup label="' + $(this).data('optgroup') + '" />').appendTo($select2);
                            $(this).appendTo($optgroup);
                            if (!$parent.children().length) $parent.remove();
                        });

                        return false;
                    });
                    $('#remove').click(function () {
                        var $el = $('#secilisecenekler option:selected');

                        $el.each(function(){
                            groupName = $(this).data('optgroup'),
                                $parent = $(this).parent(),
                                $optgroup = $select1.find('optgroup[label="' + groupName + '"]');
                            if (!$optgroup.length) $optgroup = $('<optgroup label="' + $(this).data('optgroup') + '" />').appendTo($select1);
                            $(this).appendTo($optgroup);
                            if (!$parent.children().length) $parent.remove();
                        });

                        return false;
                    });
                });
            </script>
```